# How can I get my game to move on to next item if guesser answers correctly?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a guessing game, and I need help with refreshing the font after every correct guess the user makes. I set up my code so that the font changes every time the page is refreshed:

```
  <script>
    var fontType = 
    [ "Arial", "Verdana", "Helvetica", "Times New Roman", "Arial Black", "Comic 
    Sans", "Georgia", "Tahoma", "Comic Sans MS"];


    var num;
    num=Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
    document.getElementById("fontfamily").style.fontFamily =fontType[num];
    console.log(num)
 </script>
```

This works successfully. This is the code I have set up for when the user/player is guessing:

```
function Correct() {
    var correct = ""; // correct answer
    var guess = ""; // user guess   
    var NumberOfGuesses = 0;

    guess=document.getElementById("guess").value;
    correct=document.getElementById("fontfamily").style.fontFamily;

    if (guess == correct && NumberOfGuesses <3) {
        alert("Correct! The font is " + correct + " . On to the next one!");
    } else { 
        alert("that's not it...try again");
        NumberOfGuesses = NumberOfGuesses + 1;  
    }       
}
```

What could I do so that every time the user guesses correctly, the font automatically randomizes again? I appreciate the help.

Comment: You've randomised the font in your first script. What's stopping you using the same approach when a user guesses correctly?

Comment: judgeja, I am new to JavaScript. Was not sure if that was something I could do. Why the hatred? If you don't like it, then simply go waste your time somewhere else.

Comment: If you weren't sure if you could do it then why not try it and see what happens? You'll never learn unless you're willing to fail horribly lots at first.

Comment: because if the guessing part is already in a function, and I put the randomization in another function, how am I supposed to call a function into a function? Didn't seem correct to me...I just wanted to be sure and see if there were other methods.

Answer (score 2):

Put the randomization code in the first block into a function.  Call this function every time the User guesses correctly.